# how do i parse a array list of errors and display it as validation errors

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Hi parse a arraylist of validation errors and diaply that. I have a arraylist

```
[passwordinsufficientuniquechar, passwordmaxrepeat, passwordinsufficientuniqueno, passwordnotenoughnumbers]
```

and i have the corresponding messages in message.properties like

```
passwordcontainsusername=Your new password cannot contain your user name.
passwordtooshort=Your new password must be at least 8 characters long.
passwordtoolong=Your new password cannot exceed 50 characters.
password.change.different=The new password and the confirmed password values do not match.
passwordmaxrepeat=Your new password cannot contain more than 4 instances of the same character.
passwordequalsoldpassword=Your new password cannot be a previously used password.
passwordnotenoughnumbers=Your new password must contain at least 1 number or punctuation character.
passwordnotallowedchar=Your new password contain one or more characters that are not allowed.
password.change.validateerror=The account password and the current password do not match.
passwordnotenoughchars=Your new password must contain at least 2 letters.
passwordlessthan24hours=You cannot change your password more than three times in 24 hours.
passwordinsufficientuniquechar = Your new password must contain at least 5 unique characters.
passwordinsufficientuniqueno =Your new password must contain at least 2 unique numbers (symbols count as numbers).
```

I am using a webflow. So how do I parse those messages to o/p to display messages from my properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grails convention is to put your messages in `grails-app/i18n/messages.properties`.  Then in your views you can use the `g:message` tag:

```
<g:message code="passwordtooshort"/>
```

If you have an array of message codes, you can do it like this:

```
<g:each in="${messageCodes}">
    <g:message code="${it}"/>
</g:each>
```

The views are typically the best place to do this, but if you need to do a translation inside of a controller, you can do it like so:

```
def translation = message(code: 'passwordtooshort')  // single code
def translations = messageCodes.collect { message(code: it) } // list of codes
```

Comment: def translations helped to put all the messages from properties file to the object.How do I bind the translation object to command object and show it as error message??

Comment: Typically you put constraints on your command object and grails creates errors on the command object when validate is called.  The command class name is combined with the field name and constraint name to make the key that gets looked up in messages.properties.

Comment: yup that worked....i forgot to add the command object to flow . That was creating errors. Thanks for the reply.